# sem_open sets ENAMETOOLONG for less than 64 characters names on Mac OS X 10.6.6 HFS+

Tags: macos, filenames, semaphore

in our college project, the following call is made:

sem_t *handle = sem_open("/6770::BitCompressedVector::allocate", 512, 420, 1);

As the title says, errno is set to ENAMETOOLONG, indicating that the first parameter (name) either exceeds PATH_MAX (1024 characters), or a pathname component exceeds NAME_MAX (255 characters).

The binary is executed in a 62 characters long path. Reducing the path length to 14 characters didn't help. When using "/6770::B::a", everything is fine. But this is no solution to us.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.6 with an HFS+ volume and the Xcode developer toolset 3.2.6. On my team mates MacBooks (Mac OS X 10.6.x, HFS+) and our Ubuntu 10.10 ext4 systems, the code works without errors.

What's the reason for the different behaviour on my system? Is there a workaround that does not need a change to the code?

Answer (score 2):

The Os X man page for `sem_open` states:

> [ENAMETOOLONG]     name exceeded SEM_NAME_LEN characters.

I don't have that OS, but google seems to indicate that `SEM_NAME_LEN` would be 31.

Comment: It's right the OS X man pages state this, thanks, I didn't know this! But can you tell me the source for that SEM_NAME_LEN on OS X should be 31? I only stumble upon this number for the Chromium sources. Though it seems to be correct for my system, I'd like to read that constant out and compare it with my team mates systems, as they can execute our project's code without errors. But I can't find any library/header to read out the value, any hints?